# How are IAM roles that are defined backed up and audited in GCP?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-iam

We are new to GCP. We created custom roles and will be updating them. How are they backed up so that we can recover them? How can we audit the changes in those roles?

Comment: Edit your question and expand on exactly what you are asking and you want to do. Google Cloud IAM is a managed service. Do you want to back up IAM yourself, or are you asking how Google backs up IAM? For auditing, do you mean you want to access logs that track changes? Or are you asking how to design an auditing system?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose there's no explicit backup but one idea is to create some script or documentation based on Google Cloud SDK to relate the creation roles commands. The documentation [has a guide](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-custom-roles#iam-custom-roles-list-gcloud) on how to create it using the SDK

Also you can check your custom roles created for project:

```
gcloud iam roles list --project <your-project-id>
```

Or for your organization:

```
gcloud iam roles list --organization <your-organization-id>
```

To audit changes in custom roles, use [the activity page](https://console.cloud.google.com/home/activity?folder=&organizationId=<your-organization-id>&supportedpurview=project) on cloud console

Answer (score 0):

You can use an Infrastructure as Code service to backup, recreate or track the change in the custom IAM role. GCP offers Cloud Deployment Manager (https://cloud.google.com/deployment-manager) which you can use for any IAM policy backup or custom role management. For example, by deploying the config below, you can create a custom role for project:

```
 resources:
  - name: custom-role
    type: gcp-types/iam-v1:projects.roles
    properties:
      parent: projects/{{ env["project"] }}
      roleId: {{ properties["roleId"] }}
      role:
        title: {{ properties["title"] }}
        description: {{ properties["description"] }}
        stage: {{ properties["stage"] }}
        includedPermissions: {{ properties["includedPermissions"] }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Like @ttfreeman said, the best way is to define roles as code. Terraform is another popular tool used for that. Then you can commit those files to a Git repo, which gives you version control. GCP has audit logs itself, but a Git repo is also a much nicer way to follow changes in my opinion.